# Angular - two way data binding from @Input not working

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, components, interaction

I'm trying to implement a custom input that accepts only numeric values by reseting the rest to 0, using the following code for the input component:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, ElementRef, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'debounce-input',
    template: '<input type="text" [placeholder]="placeholder" [(ngModel)]="_v">'
})
export class DebounceInputComponent {
    @Input() placeholder: string
    @Input() delay: number = 300

    _v: string

    @Input()
    get v(): string {
        return this._v
    }

    set v(_value) {
        this._v = _value
        this.valueChange.emit(this.v)
    }

    @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()

    @Output() value: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        const eventStream = Observable.fromEvent(elementRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .map(() => this.v)
            .debounceTime(this.delay)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
        eventStream.subscribe((obj) => this.value.emit({v: this.v}))
    }
}
```

The component above is imported within AppComponent using the following code:

1. HTML part:

   ```
   <div style="text-align:center">
     <debounce-input [v]="mynumber"
     delay="1000"
     placeholder="Type something..."
     (value)="handle($event)">
     </debounce-input>
   </div>
   ```
2. TypeScript part:

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     title = 'app';

     mynumber = 0

     handle(obj) {
       console.log(obj.v)
       if (isNaN(Number(obj.v))) {
         console.log('trying to reset invalid input to 0')
         this.mynumber = 0
       }
     }}
   ```

The problem is whenever I type a non-numeric value, the `AppComponent` fails to reset the input to 0, although the "trying to reset invalid input to 0" message gets shown within the console.

What is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: what is the value of `console.log(obj.v)` ? did you try with obj.target.value?

Comment: @Niladri It's the same as any value I type in the input component.

Comment: do you think you could set up a stackblitz for us to play with you code?

Comment: @BorisLobanov I tried to do so, but stackblitz failed to detect the component I added.

Comment: Whats the issue the question explanation is to confusing?? Do you want to restrict users for your input fields as `type="number"` or say `type="text"`

Comment: @mayur Yes, maybe in my case it was better to use type="number", but now I want to know why the two-way binding doesn't work.

Comment: @Kais did you registered your component in app.module.ts?

Comment: @BorisLobanov No, because there is no app.module.ts within the listed files.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/if1m0r

Comment: @BorisLobanov Ah Ok, sorry. It's done but it is now stuck on "loading" https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvwjpj.

Comment: replace app-root selector with my-app

Comment: @BorisLobanov Done.

Comment: I think I solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You @Input value was not changed because `mynumber` in the parent was not changing from the child changes. I added this functionality and it worked:

```
handle(obj) {
    console.log(obj.v)
    if (isNaN(Number(obj.v))) {
      console.log('trying to reset invalid input to 0')
      this.mynumber = 0;
    } else {
      this.mynumber = obj.v; // add this line
    }
  }
```

P.S.
I'd still, however, consider restricting your input to numeric type only and adding some filter to prevent setting numbers like '0123'.

Comment: I updated the code as you mentioned, but I am still getting the same problem - the input doesn't get reset to 0 after typing 'a'.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kscfaw works for me. have a look, maybe there's something you are missing?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I think the delay is causing the problem. If you type 1, then give it a second, then type 'a' it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

modify the setter in your input component, and make ngModel pointing to the v instead of _v.

```
  import {Component, Input, Output, ElementRef, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

  @Component({
      selector: 'debounce-input',
      template: '<input type="text" [placeholder]="placeholder" [(ngModel)]="v">'
  })
  export class DebounceInputComponent {
      @Input() placeholder: string
      @Input() delay: number = 300

      _v: string

      @Input()
      get v(): string {
          return this._v
      }

      set v(_value) {
        if (isNaN(Number(_value))) {
          console.log('trying to reset invalid input to 0')
          this._v = '0';
          return;
        }
          this._v = _value
          this.valueChange.emit(this.v)
      }

      @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()

      @Output() value: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>()

      constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
          const eventStream = Observable.fromEvent(elementRef.nativeElement, 'keyup')
              .map(() => this.v)
              .debounceTime(this.delay)
              .distinctUntilChanged()
          eventStream.subscribe((obj) => this.value.emit({v: this.v}))
      }
  }
```